# How to send a packet to all switches using ryu controller?

Tags: sdn, openflow, ryu

I need to measure link delay in Ryu controller. I want to send a packet-out message for all switches by the controller and calculate the time between the sent packet-out message and received the packet-in message. I am a beginner in Ryu and don't know how to send a packet with specific EtherType such as 0x8fc to all switches. I have obtained the MAC of all switches and build a packet. how I can send a packet with specific EtherType to all switches? I don't know what is the db parameter for every switch?

```
    def send_packet(self, dp, port, pkt):
        ofproto = dp.ofproto
        parser = dp.ofproto_parser
        pkt.serialize()
        data = pkt.data
        action = [parser.OFPActionOutput(port=port)]

        out = parser.OFPPacketOut(
            datapath=dp, buffer_id=ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER,
            in_port=ofproto.OFPP_CONTROLLER,
            actions=action, data=data)
        dp.send_msg(out)

def create_packet(self):
        i=l=0
        for l in range(1,len(self.adjacency)+1):
            #print("\n")
            for i in self.adjacency[l]:
                ethertype = 0x8fc
                dst = self.macaddr(i)
                src = self.macaddr(l) 
                e = ethernet.ethernet(dst, src, ethertype)                
                p = packet.Packet()
                p.add_protocol(e)
                p.add_protocol(time.time())
                p.serialize()
                port=self.adjacency[l][i]
                send_packet(self, dp **??????** , port, p):
```

Answer (score 0):

DP is the abbreviation for DataPathID that is kind of Uniq ID for an OpenFlow switch in your network.

According to the [OpenFlow specification](https://www.opennetworking.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/openflow-spec-v1.3.3.pdf):

> “The datapath_id field uniquely identifies a datapath. The lower 48
>   bits are intended for the switch MAC address, while the top 16 bits
>   are up to the implementer. An example use of the top 16 bits would be
>   a VLAN ID to distinguish multiple virtual switch instances on a single
>   physical switch.”

If you're using Mininet and for example, you run linear topology:

```
mn --controller remote --topo linear,3
```

Your topology will be:

```
s1 -- s2 -- s3

 |    |      |

h1    h2     h3
```

DataPathID's will be:

s1:        0x0000000000000001

s2:        0x0000000000000002

s3:        0x0000000000000003

Pay attention that in other testbeds this numbers may be different but they're alway 16 digit hex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `p.add_protocol(time.time())` would work.

Create a protocol class rather:

```py
from ryu.lib.packet import packet_base, packet_utils


class timep(packet_base.PacketBase):
    _PACK_STR = '!I'
    _PACK_LEN = struct.calcsize(_PACK_STR)
    _MIN_LEN = _PACK_LEN + struct.calcsize(_CHECKSUM_STR)
    _TYPE = {}

    def __init__(self, timestamp, payload_len=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.timestamp = int(timestamp)
        self.payload_len = payload_len

    def __len__(self):
        return timep._PACK_LEN

    @classmethod
    def parser(cls, buf):
        (timestamp, payload_len) = struct.unpack_from(cls._PACK_STR, buf)
        payload = buf[ppdp._MIN_LEN : ppdp._MIN_LEN + payload_len]
        msg = cls(timestamp, payload_len)
        return msg, None, payload

    def serialize(self, payload, prev):
        length = len(self)
        buf = bytearray(length)
        self.payload_len = len(payload)
        
        struct.pack_into(ppdp._PACK_STR, buf, 0,
            self.timestamp,
            self.payload_len
        )
        return buf
```

No you can do `p.add_protocol(timep(time.time()))`